# Title Bar Stuck on Theme

Tags: titlebar

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10. I downloaded a couple themes and tried switching them up using GNOME Tweak. The windows will change themes but the Title Bar is stuck on Ambiance. It was switching themes OK right after the clean install, so I tried removing the downloads from .themes folder. Also tried "unity --replace", "compiz --replace", and restarting. Anyone have any other ideas?? Thanks.

Also

-ben

Comment: Are you sure you changed the *Window theme* combobox and not just the GTK+ theme combobox? I have made that mistake before.

Comment: I did change the GTK+ theme combobox because I thought that was sufficient.  I don't really understand themes too well.  I just found a setting in Appearance called Theme and that DID solve the problem.  If this is the right place, now I'm wondering how to install new themes because I dropped some things into .themes and they don't show up in Appearance.

Answer (score 1):

*According to OP in a comment*:

> Did change the GTK+ theme combobox because I thought that was
>   sufficient. I don't really understand themes too well. I just found a
>   setting in Appearance called Theme and that DID solve the problem.